# How to pass the value of a form select input to a php file using AJAX without submitting it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the value of a form select input from an HTML form to a php file without submitting it.

How may I do that?

This is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Provincia</label>
<select class="form-control" name="userDomicilioProvincia">
<option id ="userDomicilioProvincia" name="userDomicilioProvincia"> </option>
<option value="Capital Federal">Capital Federal</option>
<option value="Gran Buenos Aires">Gran Buenos Aires</option> 
<option value="Buenos Aires">Provincia de Buenos Aires</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

And here's my ajax call:

```
$('#userDomicilioProvincia').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ubicacion.php",
       provincia: {text:$(this).val()}
    });
});
```

I'm trying to test this using the browser's console, I got into the form, select one option and in the console I type `var Provincia` and it returns `undefined`.

How may I do that?

Comment: `$("#userDomicilioProvincia")`means select the element with attribute `id="userDomicilioProvincia "`. If you want to get your select element that have the name attribute set, use this selector : `$('select[name="userDomicilioProvincia"]')`

Comment: But it's better to set the `id` attribute to the `select` element rather than using the (select) tag to find the element. The `id` selector is MUCH faster. You can read something about selector performance [here](https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

Put the `id` attribute on the `select` and instead of the `option`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userDomicilioProvincia').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ubicacion.php",
            data: { provincia: $(this).val() }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Provincia</label>
    <select id="userDomicilioProvincia" class="form-control" name="userDomicilioProvincia">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="Capital Federal">Capital Federal</option>
        <option value="Gran Buenos Aires">Gran Buenos Aires</option> 
        <option value="Buenos Aires">Provincia de Buenos Aires</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! How may I access that value in php? I'm trying with `var_dump($_POST['provincia']);` and it's null.

Comment: @Rosamunda sorry, there is an other mistake in the jQuery code. I corrected it. I changed `provincia: {text:$(this).val()}` to: `data: { provincia: $(this).val() }`. data is a javascript object which you send as `POST` to the server (PHP). Try again, `var_dump($_POST['provincia']);` should work now.