# How to pass data to the server using ajax and PHP? $_POST['data'] won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form that I want to send to the server (using a PHP script) some information before it gets submitted. I'm using .ajax() jQuery function as well.

Here's my demo.html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Provincia</label>
<select id ="demo" class="form-control">
<option> </option>
<option value="op1">Opcion 1</option>
<option value="op2">Opcion 2</option> 
<option value="op3">Opcion 3</option> 
</select>
</div>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').on('change', do_something);
    console.log('ready');
});

function do_something() {
    var selected = $('#demo').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:        'delete.php',
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        data:       { selected }
    });
    console.log(selected);
    $('#demo2').append(selected);
}
</script>
```

I don't know what to do to get the selected item.
I get to print the selected item on the screen and in the console. How do I get that with PHP?

The delete.php file has only this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['data']);
var_dump($_POST['selected']);
```

Because I want to know what's on the server, but nothing gets printed. How may I get what's been selected?

Comment: Use `data:{selected: selected}` or `data:{data: selected}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the value of a form select input to a php file using AJAX without submitting it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946984/how-to-pass-the-value-of-a-form-select-input-to-a-php-file-using-ajax-without-su)

Comment: @Titus OP is using valid syntax, I don't see what your suggestion would help.

Comment: @chiliNUT Yes, you're right. `data:{selected}` is valid `ES2015` syntax. My bad.

Comment: please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data` attribute to set values you want to send to `PHP` and you can also set `success` to execute code when the request is successful.

```
function do_something() {
    var selected = $('#demo').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:        'delete.php',
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        data:       { selected: selected },
        success: function (response) {
            // response comes from PHP
            if (response.result == true) {
                // request was success
            }else if (response.result == false) {
                // request was not successful
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your PHP, you can access the values through `$_POST`

```
<?php

$selected = $_POST['selected'];

// rest of the code here
// you can also send response to Javascript here
// for failure echo json_encode(['result' => false]);
// for success echo json_encode(['result' => true])
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will fail since response is already parsed due to `dataType` being set

Answer (score 0):

The `data` attribute in the AJAX options specifies the name of the value you are looking for. Your `data` object is:

```
{
    value: selected
}
```

so simply use `$_POST['value']` to get the selected item name. If you ever want to know what's in the POST object, just run a vardump like so:

```
vardump($_POST);
```

that may help you answer questions like these in the future.